# Would logging into Chase bank website be an example of Asymmetric cryptography?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, asymmetric, key

Also anyone who is familiar with Outlook, is sending digital signed messages a process of Asymmetric cryptography? Since it uses a public key and requires your Smartcard PIN before you can actually send. It also adds a digital certificate, but I am a little confused.

Comment: What are you confused about? The difference between symmetric and asymmetric encryption?

Comment: My confusion is the question versus the subject. What does the Chase Bank website have to do with Outlook?

Answer (score 2):

Your question reveals the lack of some basic conceptual understanding in how cryptography and encryption works.

> Is using digital signatures an examples of using asymmetric
>   cryptography?

**Yes it is.**

Asymmetric encryption means 2 keys are used to encrypt and to decrypt a message. A example of a widely used asymmetric cryptographic algorithm used for encryption of email is RSA.

Digital signatures **use asymmetric cryptography** to generate a cryptographic hash of the outgoing message to be sent using the sender's private key. The sender's **private key** is known only to the sender of the email. The receiver of the email uses the cryptographic hash to decrypt the message received using the **public key** of the sender. If the integrity of the message has been compromised, the resulting message will be different and the signature invalid / corrupted.

The public key of the sender is **tied to the sender's identity through the assistance of a third party - A certificate authority - CA**. This CA issues a certificate that uniquely identifies the public key as belonging to the sender of the message. The addition of the CA is to ensure that a hacker cannot impersonate the sender by substituting a fraudulent public key in place of the true, correct public key of the sender. An assumption here is that the certificate has not been revoked and listed on the CRL kept and updated by the CA.

The purpose of digital signatures is to guarantee integrity, non - repudiation of the message, and of authenticity of the sender.